# Unable to send E-mail via Bugzilla Defect Tracking Tool

Tags: email, bugzilla

I have installed Bugzilla 4.4.9 in my Cent OS system. When I report a bug to an assignee , only the Bug entry gets stored in the My Bugs section when seen into the assignees account. How does one send E-mail to a assignee to notify the assignee about the bug. The mail_delivery method I am using is SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

You should see a message on the screen after submitting the bug that shows the users that were sent emails and those users who were excluded.

If the assignee was excluded you are looking at one of the following 2 reasons:

1. Each user can configure whether they receive emails for different
   event. Go to Preferences/Email Preferences to see the options.
2. Additionally all email can be disabled for a user by the
   administrator. Go to Administration/Users find the user and look at
   the Bugmail Disabled field.

If the assignee was on the send to list and they didn't receive it you need to look at your email system.